# Excel Error while opening Downloaded Excel file from Dynamics 365 - Customer Service

Tags: excel, export, dynamics-365

In Dynamics 365 v9.0.2 [Version 1710 (9.0.2.2078)], I am getting below error intermittently while opening an excel file downloaded from Advanced find or any of the view's  - "Export to Excel" functionality.   Sometimes, it is repeating up to more than 10-15 times continuously before letting me successfully open excel file.

[image]

Did anyone else also face any similar issue? What could be the root cause of this issue, a bug in D365 9.0.2 or Office installed on the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before.
In my case the issue was basically in Data (Crm) has special characters into it such as *, !, #, %, and so on.

Please try and export onyl 1 or 2 rows where data does not have any fancy special characters. This should help you.